# extract value between specific string and colon in R

Tags: r, regex, sqldf

I have a table example like this

```
No, Memo
  1, Date: 2020/10/22 City: UA Note: True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.
  2, Date: 2022/11/01 City: CH Note: Sweat is the lubricant of success.
  3, Date: 2022y11m1d City: UA Note: Every noble work is at first impossible.
  4, Date: 2022y2m15d City: AA Note: Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely.
```

I want to extract string after `Date:` ,`City:` and `Note:`.
For example at NO. 1,I need to extract the "2020/10/22" which is between `Date:` and `City:`, "UA" which is between `City:` and `Note:`, and the "True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime."  which is after `Note:`.

Desired Output like :

```
 No Date       City Note
  1 2020/10/22 UA   True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.
  2 2022/11/01 CH   Sweat is the lubricant of success.
  3 2022y11m1d UA   Every noble work is at first impossible.
  4 2022y2m15d AA   Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely.
```

Does anyone know an answer for that?Any help would be great.Thank you.

Comment: You could eventually just do a regex replace by searching for "Date", "City" or "Note", followed by ":" and spaces and optionally prefixed by a comma: https://regex101.com/r/psVSuG/1 I replaced it by a tabulation, but you could leave your space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution using regex and `stringr` and `dplyr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(
  text = "No; Memo
  1; Date: 2020/10/22 City: UA Note: True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.
  2; Date: 2022/11/01 City: CH Note: Sweat is the lubricant of success.
  3; Date: 2022y11m1d City: UA Note: Every noble work is at first impossible.
  4; Date: 2022y2m15d City: AA Note: Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely.",
  sep = ";",
  header = T
)

df_test <- df %>% mutate(date = str_extract(Memo, "(?<=Date: )(.*)(?= City)"),
                         city = str_extract(Memo, "(?<=City: )(.*)(?= Note)"),
                         note = str_extract(Memo, "(?<=Note: ).*")) %>%
  select(-Memo)
```

```
> df_test
  No       date city                                                   note
1  1 2020/10/22   UA            True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.
2  2 2022/11/01   CH                     Sweat is the lubricant of success.
3  3 2022y11m1d   UA               Every noble work is at first impossible.
4  4 2022y2m15d   AA Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely.
```

The regex matches everything between the groups specified using positive lookahead and loohbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Place a newline before each keyword in Memo at which point it is in dcf format so read that using read.dcf.  This is general, not depending on the particular keywords in Memo, and does not depend on any packages.

```
DF |>
  transform(Memo = gsub("(\\w+: )", "\n\\1", Memo)) |>
  with(data.frame(No, read.dcf(textConnection(Memo))))
```

giving

```
  No       Date City                                                   Note
1  1 2020/10/22   UA            True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.
2  2 2022/11/01   CH                     Sweat is the lubricant of success.
3  3 2022y11m1d   UA               Every noble work is at first impossible.
4  4 2022y2m15d   AA Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely.
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(
  No = 1:4,
  Memo = c(
    "Date: 2020/10/22 City: UA Note: True mastery of any skill takes a lifetime.",
    "Date: 2022/11/01 City: CH Note: Sweat is the lubricant of success.",
    "Date: 2022y11m1d City: UA Note: Every noble work is at first impossible.",
    "Date: 2022y2m15d City: AA Note: Live beautifully, dream passionately, love completely."
  )
)
```